# What is the number at the top for the results for ls -l?

Tags: filesystems, directory, ls, c

When you type in `ls -l`, there is a number on the first line labeled "`total 22037`"? What does this number mean? I am attempting to write my own version of `ls -l`( in C), and how do I get this value or calculate it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l

Comment: Was just going to post the same question as sinclair. For implementation, you can ask in SO.

Comment: These are two completely different questions.  The second (implementation) belongs on SO.  The first *could* fit here, but it's already been answered quite well on SO, as linked above.

Answer (score 3):

To implement *standard* UNIX command, you should check POSIX, e.g. at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/. For `ls` command: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html you will find the format of output:

> If any of the -l, -n, -s, -g, or -o options is specified, each list of files within the directory shall be preceded by a status line indicating the number of file system blocks occupied by files in the directory in 512-byte units if the -k option is not specified, or 1024-byte units if the -k option is specified, rounded up to the next integral number of units, if necessary. In the POSIX locale, the format shall be:
>
> "total %u\n",